# Laravel route group controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and wonder if I can not only group routes by name prefixes and route prefixes but also controllers since they all use the same controller. The documentation didn't provide anything the like. In Laravel 4 there were [implicit controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) available by using `Route::controller()` but that's not what I'm looking for since this won't be implicit. To cut a long story short, here's what I currently have:

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'my-route', 'as' => 'myRoute.' ] , function () {
    Route::get('/{viewMode?}', 'MyRouteController@index')->name('index')->where('viewMode', '[a-z]+');
    Route::get('/ajax', 'MyRouteController@ajax')->name('ajax');
});
```

And it should look something like that:

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'my-route', 'as' => 'myRoute.', 'controller' => 'MyRouteController' ] , function () {
    Route::get('/{viewMode?}', 'index')->name('index')->where('viewMode', '[a-z]+');
    Route::get('/ajax', 'ajax')->name('ajax');
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think so. You could shorthand your code a bit by adding a `$controller = 'MyRouteController';` in your `group()`, then `Route::get('/ajax', "{$controller}@ajax")`, but the approach you have outlined doesn't seem to be a thing (which is too bad, it seems like a useful feature).

Comment: Hmmm, that's not much shorter (and would require an additional line of code) … Yeah, too bad. Thank's for your answer anyway!

Comment: Haha yeah, it's not much better, and I get what you're trying to do. I wonder if a modified `Resource` could work: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers (since those specify a Controller for a set of routes)

Comment: Frankly I thought about that, too. But I discarded that idea, because `Resource`s are mainly used for RESTful APIs and therefore unnecessary routes are created (unnecessary but not problematic per se). But if I intend to misuse `Resource`s for that purpose I have to [supplement the controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers) upfront in order to achieve that behavior which seems a little messy and undesirable to me. Nonetheless, that might work if someone wants to utilize that approach …

Comment: Yeah, all fair points. I also don't use `Resource`s much for a lot of similar reasons. Anyway, it sounds like you've thought about this quite a bit; perhaps consider presenting the idea to the Laravel framework as a feature request (although I'm not sure about the process, if you need to have the solution coded yourself, etc, but might be something to look into).

Comment: I started a [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/34294) summarizing our deliberations here to see how the chances are. Thanks for the nice exchange so far!

Comment: No problem! Happy to throw my 2-cents into this, since I could see myself using this approach. Best of luck with that :)